# Read a file from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I want to read a file from github repository in my ruby script. Say I want to read Gemfile from my repo on github, URL for which would be like: "http://www.github.com/myrepo/blob/master/Gemfile".

I tried using `File.readLink("http://www.github.com/myrepo/blob/master/Gemfile")` but this gives me error saying `"'readlink': No such file or directory @ rb_readlink"`.

How do I read a file using the github URL?

Comment: have you try the open-uri gem?

Comment: Yes I used open-uri gem. The file I get is in html format. Is there a way I can get the contents in the file as it is, I mean not in html format?

Comment: Oh I found what was returning it in html format. Ignore it. Instead of blob I was supposed to use raw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to fetch raw content from github files like:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/myrepo/master/Gemfile"
uri = URI(uri)
file = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

Comment: With that I get "`initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen" error.

Comment: @techie_woman Sorry, was busy and didn't tested the code. Have a look on updated answer

Comment: Just use [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html): `require 'open-air'; file = open("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/myrepo/master/Gemfile").read`. OpenURI handles redirects whereas Net::HTTP will not.

Answer (score 0):

With the below code, I was able to read the content of the file.

```
require 'open-uri'
raw_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/myrepo/master/Gemfile"
open(raw_url) {|f|
  f.each_line {|line| p line}
}
```