# Read a private file from Github in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081517/read-a-file-from-github) for initial solutions. However, the file I want to reference in my rails project is in a private file. When I perform the following code:

```
  uri = URI("https://.../config.yml")
  file = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  config = YAML.load(file)
```

The 'file' has the contents of the sign-in page of github. Is it possible to pass credentials to access this private repo's file? Additionally, is this safe to do?

Comment: If it's done over HTTPS, I suppose; it might be a better idea to use the API, though.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to execute these git api calls on a private repo? These endpoints https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#contents seem to only be used for public repo's.

Comment: The API works for both public and private repos as stated at the top of that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the credentials via a header. Something like this should work

```rb
token = "123"
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['Authorization'] = "Token #{token}"

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
```

Otherwise I also suggest to just use the Github client library [Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb#making-requests).

Comment: Would you happen to know why I might get a 404 even with this authorization? https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content states that if don't specify :path, it should still return contents of the root directory of the repo. However, I am still getting a 404 in this case. I am assuming it be because of https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#authentication. Oddly, using the token or basic authentication's username and pwd to login to view the repo via a browser works but not when doing GET requests via postman/other methods.

Comment: Without seeing the exact code it's difficult to answer this.